# What tests, if any, can I execute to determine whether a PV panel has deteriorated?

Tags: solar-cell, testing

So I'm possessed of an aged Photo-voltaic panel (around 15years) that came with a night-lamp.

When placed in the sun here (21.17, 79.09) - on a sunny day the multimeter shows me as much as 11V from the panel. The SLA, admittedly aged, had to be replaced around 7 years ago - and I've just changed the battery again after the lamp had lain unused in the corner for a 2-3 years.

The SLA is rated at 6V 4.5Ah; the original battery was rated for 4Ah.

At the time of purchase the seller had intimated to my late Father the PV panel was good for atleast 10 years.

What tests, if any, can I execute to determine whether the PV panel has deteriorated?

Comment: Put a calibrated illumination on it, create a VI curve and compare that to the specifications.

Comment: If you don't have accurate measurements of its original performance ten years ago, you cannot tell if it has deteriorated. All you can tell now is how it is currently performing - and if it is still within its original spec (if you have that). Re-measuring in a year or so will tell you if it is actively deteriorating.

Comment: @everyone - Try and make sense of my answer below and ask more questions if not clear BUT you are welcome to contact me offlist if desired. See my profile for email address (do not use facebook). (apptechnz at gmail) ...

Answer (score 2):

> What tests, if any, can I execute to determine whether the PV panel has deteriorated?

See below.

1. Calculate efficiency
2. Probably more useful - simply measure Isc with DMM ammeter by shorting output of PV panel (NOT battery) in full bright sun into DMM 10A range - that will tell you charging time.

For Nagpur

- Tcharge hours ~~= Capacity_Ah / (Isc x 0.8)

SSH = sunshine hours of equivalent full sun
Max available SSH in Nagpur ~= 4 in winter and 6 in summer (see below)

eg if Isc = 500 mA, battery = 4.5 Ah then
Tcharge = 4.5 / (0.5 x 0.8) = 11 hours
So even in summer the battery would only about half charge.
However, ideallt only 50% of battery capacity should be used to extend battery life substantially.

---

What type of PV panel - amorphous, crystalline silicon, ... .

Voltage seldom degrades much.
Short circuit current (into eg DMM 10A range in full sun shows likely loaded I + say 10% to 20%.

In following mp = max power point.
Vmp x Imp/(Voc x Isc) = fill factor.
90% is excellent.
80% not unexpected.
70% getting down.
Lower worse.

Imp will degrade with age.
If crystalline silicon you get some degradation from cells, more usually from  EVA bonding agent yellowing, glass may lose some transmission.

Old crystalline silicon may be 10%-12% efficient.
Full midday bright sun summer ~~~= 1000 W/m^2
So power out = active_m^2 x 1000 x efficiency x (1-glass loss)   = Watts.
Active area is say 90% total. Kaa = 0.9 Use lower if lower.
Glass loss is say 10%. Kg = 0.9
0 < Z < 1 = efficiency

P = A x 1000 x Kaa x Kg x Z
so Z = P / (A x 1000 x Kaa x Kg)
For above

- **Efficiency Z =** Power_Watts / (Area_m^2  x 800)

eg if panel area = 0.1 m^2 and Power max = say 5 Watts
efficiency = Z = 5 / (0.1 x 800) = 6.25%
This is the effective material Z.

I'd expect 10-12% for Silicon.
If EVA glass etc has aged it may be lower or much lower

BUT

Best test is WHAT do you NEED.
New panels are cheapish.

Where are you?
Go to www.gaisma .com and see how many sunshine hours (SSH) a day you get summer and winter. (Chart with W/m^2 = sunshine hours).

Ah - Nagpur!(I was in Puna last year - Maharashtra is a big place !!!)

Annual insolation in Nagpur, india [here](http://www.gaisma.com/en/location/nagpur.html)

This table shows Nagpur typical daily SSH by month.
Worst 3 months = July-Sep at about say 4 SSH/day 
Best 3 month = March-May as say 6++ SSH/day

Charging a 4.5 Ah in say 4 hours takes somewhat over 1.2 A from the panel in full sun. 
BUT if you want the battery to last long you should not discharge it to more than say 50% depth = 2.25 Ah used so say 0.6A peak in full sun. As panel is not always at optimum angle etc more is needed but start with that.

To get needed 6.9V = 7V needed to float SLA at 13.7V you need about a 10V at max power PV.

10V x 0.6A = 6W PV - say 5W.
For full charge in 4 hours you want a 10V 10W rated PV.
But you will want MORE due to non ideal conditions and mostly people will sell you less.

A 5W panel may cost 50 INR if you try very hard to find one - but probably more.

A panel that give short circuit current of 60-0 mA in winter will charge a half discharged battery in 4+ hours in summer.
400 mA will charge it in 6 hours in summer.
If you use all the battery capacity a full charge needs 1.2A+ in 4 hours in Winter and
800 mA in 6 hours in Winter.

More always helps.

A lamp that is 15 years old will be a bulb or CFL lamp.
An LED lamp will make MUCH better us of the panel and battery energy.

[image]

Comment: Assuming the panel is up to it I *hope* to replace the CFL with an LED strip. The tricky part will be dissipating the heat from the LEDs ...